# Element in Div will not get centered

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to center elements inside a div to no avail. Please tell me what i'm doing wrong here. Please find my html and css code below:

```
<div class="one-column-960">
        <div class="about1"><a name="about"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/team-2.png" alt="" />
                        <h3>Jose Togbe</h3>
                        <p class="job-role">Information Architect/ UX Designer</p>
                        <p>Entrepreneur and CEO of Planmesh by day, information architect and UX designer by night. Jose has worked with various agencies including Oho interactive, O2KL, Revsquare, and ICC Lowe.</p> 
                    </li>
                </ul>   
        </div>      
    </div><!-- close about us header -->
```

CSS:

```
.one-column-960{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center; 
}

.about1 ul li {
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove `position: absolute;` from li

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
.one-column-960{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center; 
}

.about1 ul li {
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
}
```

[Live Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lAwFz)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove `position: absolute;` from your `.about1 ul li{}` class.

Answer (score 0):

I removed some stuff from your css, but here is a result:

```
.one-column-960{
    width: 100%;
}

.about1 ul
{
    width:300px;
    margin:0px auto;
    display:block;
}

.about1 ul li {
    margin: 0 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this css property:

.about1 ul li {

width: 300px;

margin: auto;

}

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do the following in code html

```
<div class="one-column-960">
    <div class="about1" ALIGN=CENTER><a name="about"></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="photo.jpg" alt="" />
                <h3>Jose Togbe</h3>
                <p class="job-role">Information Architect/ UX Designer</p>
                <p>Entrepreneur and CEO of Planmesh by day, information architect and UX designer by night. Jose has worked with various agencies including Oho interactive, O2KL, Revsquare, and ICC Lowe.</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><!-- close about us header -->
```

is not the best solution but it works, it would be better to add this css